# Can a Variable or a Constant store a operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like if `10k` is evaluated the result is `0.1`. I tried something like this:

```
const k = /100;
```

But, of course, it throws an error.

Is there a way I can achieve something similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function:

```js
const k = num => num / 100;
console.log(k(10));
```